# C struct pointer

Tags: c, struct

I was trying to understand some code written by others. But I am not very familiar with C. Could anyone explain the following code? Thx ahead!

```
struct cell *ptr = (struct cell* ) malloc ( (input * 1024) * sizeof(struct cell));
```

Comment: It is a basic dynamic allocation of an array of `struct cell` values, and the size of the array is `input * 1024` element.  The cast is not necessary in C; it is necessary if you were misguided enough to be using `malloc()` in C++.  The value in `ptr` should be checked before it is used just in case the allocation failed (in which case, `ptr` is null).

Comment: Do not... Um. *Tell them* not to cast the result of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code creates a pointer of type `struct cell` named `ptr` which points to a memory location- a sequence of (input*1024) number of blocks, where each block is of size `sizeof(struct cell)`

This is dynamic memory allocation. During runtime if there is not that much amount of free memory, it will return `NULL` and `ptr` will be pointing to `NULL` It always advised to check `ptr` for `NULL` value before playing with it.

As you have allocated the memory dynamically, it's your responsibility to free/reclaim it by calling `free(ptr)` once you are done.

Answer (score 2):

This was a way of allocating memory in the 1970s which is still sometimes seen today, perhaps due to a "cargo cult" programming mentality.

The effect is to allocate a contiguous array which has `1024 * input` number of elements, and each element is an (uninitialized) `struct cell`.

Today we would write:

```
struct cell *ptr = malloc( input * 1024 * sizeof *ptr );
```

or

```
struct cell *ptr = calloc( input * 1024, sizeof *ptr );
```

The latter will also initialize any integers in the struct to have value `0`, and any char arrays to contain empty strings; and may be faster depending on the operating system.

The `sizeof *ptr` part is necessary because the malloc family of functions expect *number of bytes* instead of *number of elements* so we must multiply by the number of bytes per element;  and if `ptr` points to an element, then `*ptr` is an element, so `sizeof *ptr` retrieves the size of that element.

For explanation of why the old style is no longer in favour, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

This code dynamically allocates a number of `struct cell`'s. The number is equal to input*1024. As a result `ptr` will be a 1D array of structs. Don't forget to `free()` it!

Also say to these others [not to cast malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

The function `malloc` is used to dynamically allocate memory, it is used when you have no prior knowledge of how large something will be beforehand. Its argument is the number of bytes you want.
 Given an input, in this case `input`, it will give you that number of struct cells times 1024. Think of it like a matrix, where 1024 is the width and input is the height. Finally the function returns the pointer to the allocated memory block which is stored in `ptr` so that you can use it.
In a object oriented language it is the equivalent of creating an array of objects, the size of the "object" is the size of the cell, input would be the number of such "arrays of objects" you are creating, and 1024 is the array length.

Comment: There is truth and confusion in this answer. The first two sentences are OK. The discussion of kilobytes is confused, I think.  The purpose here seems to be allocate an array of cells, and if the number entered in `input` is (for sake of example) `8`, then 8192 `struct cell` values will be allocated in the array.  In an OO language, this would be equivalent to creating an 'array of an object type', not just 'a new object', and `input` is not the number of objects, but 1 / 1024 of the number of objects in the array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right, the 1024 threw me off, will update my answer